# HttpClient DelegatingHandler unexpected life cycle

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

In ASP.NET Core 2.1 app I am making REST request using `HttpClient`. I am using `DelegatingHandler`s to define some common behavior. The registration i here:

```
private static void AddRestServiceDataClient<TTypedHttpClient, TTypedHttpClientImpl>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where TTypedHttpClient : class
    where TTypedHttpClientImpl : RestServiceDataClient, TTypedHttpClient
{
    var httpClientBuilder = services
        .AddHttpClient<TTypedHttpClient, TTypedHttpClientImpl>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<CachingHttpDelegatingHandler>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<ExceptionHttpDelegatingHandler>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<LoggingHttpDelegatingHandler>();
}

...

// EDIT: You should always register DelegatingHandlers as TRANSIENT (read answer for more).
services.AddScoped<ExceptionHttpDelegatingHandler>();
services.AddScoped<CachingHttpDelegatingHandler>();
services.AddScoped<LoggingHttpDelegatingHandler>();
```

I register `DelegatingHandler`s as Scoped, but in two different scopes (requests) I get the same `DelegatingHandler`. I mean that the constructor of `DelegationgHandler` is being called only once and the same instance is used across more requests (like singleton). Everything else is as expected - life cycle of other services, TypedHttpClients and HttpClient is ok.

I tested everything by breakpoint in constructor and I have testing Guid in every instance so I can distinguish instances.

When I register `DelegatingHandler`s as Transient it makes no difference.

**TL;DR** `DelegatingHandler`s are resolved like singleton even though they are registered as scoped. And this causes me mishmash in service lifestyles.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After some investigation I found out that even though `DelegatingHandler`s are resolved by dependecy injection, the lifecycle of `DelegatingHandler`s is a bit unexpected and requires deeper knowledge of `HttpClientFactory` in .NET Core 2.1.

`HttpClientFactory` creates new `HttpClient` every time, but shares `HttpMessageHandler` across multiple `HttpClient`s. More information about this you can find in [Steve Gordon's article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore).

Because actual instances of `DelegatingHandler`s are held inside `HttpMessageHandler` (recursively in `InnerHandler` property) and `HttpMessageHandler` is shared, then `DelegatingHandler`s are shared the same way and have same lifecycle as the shared `HttpMessageHandler`.

Service provider is here used only for creating new `DelegatingHandler`s when `HttpClientFactory` "decides to" - thus every `DelegatingHandler` must be registered as transient! Otherwise you would get non-deterministic behavior. `HttpClientFactory` would try to reuse already used `DelegatingHandler`.

**Workaround**

If you need to resolve dependencies in `DelegatingHandler` you can resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` in constructor and then resolve dependencies by `ServiceProvider` in `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices`.

This approach is not exactly "architecturally clean" but it is the only workaround I have found.

Example:

```
internal class MyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    protected MyDelegatingHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var serviceProvider = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var myService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, is this still the case in .net 3.1? Currently facing some issues that may be a consequence of this. In a delegating handler we are using a DbContext, and we get exceptions stating that a new operation is started while another one is still going on.

Comment: Don't forget to register `HttpContextAccessor` with `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`
This is equivalent to:
`services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Comment: This only works in ASP.NET, what about worker service that doesn't have access to the IHttpContextAccessor ?

Comment: found an article which explains the same issue as the one you observed but with more details. put it here for sharing. https://andrewlock.net/understanding-scopes-with-ihttpclientfactory-message-handlers/

Comment: Have to be careful with this type of code when using multiple threads. For example, Fire and Forget logic (`Task.Run()`) will not have access to the `HttpContext`. This code should contain a null check around it and a fallback to use the ServiceProvider.

Comment: @sergevm: "In a delegating handler we are using a DbContext" -- I'm not sure calling the database from a http pipeline is a good idea, so don't blame .NET for your tight coupling.

Comment: What would make the behavior non-deterministic if the `DelegatingHandler` is registered as Scoped?

Answer (score 5):

Starting with .Net Core 2.2 there is an alternative without using IHttpContextAccessor as a service locator to resolve scoped dependencies. See the details on this issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/issues/166).

This is most useful for .NET Core console apps:

```
// configure a client pipeline with the name "MyTypedClient"
...

// then
services.AddTransient<MyTypedClient>((s) =>
{
    var factory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpMessageHandlerFactory>();
    var handler = factory.CreateHandler(nameof(MyTypedClient));

    var otherHandler = s.GetRequiredService<MyOtherHandler>();
    otherHandler.InnerHandler = handler;
    return new MyTypedClient(new HttpClient(otherHandler, disposeHandler: false));
});
```

Comment: Why do `new HttpClient`? Can we use a client provided from `IHttpClientFactory`? `s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient(nameof(MyTypedClient));`

Comment: IHttpClientFactory will just create the HttpClient with the DelegatingHandler as singleton, it defeats the purpose of this workaround of having scoped handlers. 

You still have to `new HttpClient` but alternatively you can do this:

`var typedClientFactory=s.GetService<ITypedHttpClientFactory<MyTypedClient>>();`
`typedClientFactory.CreateClient(httpClient);`