# Delegating Handler as Transient or Singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are using http client factory and delegating handler to invoke a partner api and process the response. AuthenticationDelegating handler as shown below has a responsibility to get the required token for partner api authentication and provide it part of the api request.

**Question - Should i register AuthenticationDelegationHandler as Transient or Singleton if the token expiration is set to 24 hours?**

**startup.cs**

```
        services.AddTransient<AuthenticationDelegatingHandler>();
        var apiSettings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(APIParameters)).Get<APIParameters>();
        var apRegistrationParameters = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppRegistrationParameters)).Get<AppRegistrationParameters>();

        services.AddHttpClient("ApiSecuredClient", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiSettings.BaseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(ApiSettings.MediaType));
           
        })
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthenticationDelegatingHandler>().SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(apRegistrationParameters.LifetimeOfAuthenticationHandlerInMinutes));
```

**httpclient factory**

```
   public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequestAsync<T>(T req,                                                                            Sales360APIParameters 
 _paramenters) where T : class, IApiBaseRequest
    {
        using (var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("XXXClient"))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_paramenters.MediaType));
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, _paramenters.MediaType);
            data.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("version", _paramenters.Version));
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync(_paramenters.API, data);
            return Res;
        }
    }
```

**AuthenticationDelegatingHandler**

```
 public class AuthenticationDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
 {
    private AppRegistrationParameters _appRegistrationInfo;
    private DateTime _tokenExpirationLocalTime;
    private ILogger<AuthenticationDelegatingHandler> _logger;
    public AuthenticationDelegatingHandler(ILogger<AuthenticationDelegatingHandler> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _appRegistrationInfo = config.GetSection(nameof(AppRegistrationParameters)).Get<AppRegistrationParameters>();
        _logger = logger;

    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = null;
            if (_tokenExpirationLocalTime != null && _tokenExpirationLocalTime > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_appRegistrationInfo.TimeoutRequestInSeconds))
            {
                response = ProcessRequest(request);

                if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized || response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    response = ProcessRequest(request, true);
            }
            else
            {
                response = ProcessRequest(request, true);
            }

            return response.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("{systemId} - Error Authenticating with App. {errorCode} for " + request.Content, Constants.SystemId, Constants.ErrorCode3100);
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think the token expiration time should affect the service lifetime? Transient vs. singleton has more to do with whether your service/class is thread safe or not. It's a little unclear to me how you store/read/update the token from the posted code, so it's hard to say what effect setting it to transient or singleton will have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Custom delegating handler must always be registered as transient dependencies. All the examples in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#outgoing-request-middleware) show that custom delegating handlers must be registered as transient dependencies.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223411/httpclient-delegatinghandler-unexpected-life-cycle) and [this article](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-scopes-with-ihttpclientfactory-message-handlers/) explain the reasons behind this.

To summarize: **always register your custom delegating handlers with transient lifetime when you are using the ASP.NET core HTTP client factory**.

Notice that this guideline has nothing to do with your business logic to handle both the access token and its lifetime. It is a side effect of the way the ASP.NET core HTTP client factory handles the DI scope which uses to resolve dependencies (read the linked article for an in depth explanation).

If you want to take some ideas about how to handle access tokens and their expiration by using a delegating handler, [this project](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore) can offer you some insights.

Comment: we do not expect frequent DNS updates and also it is not a load heavy system but makes sense of being transient. In that case what would be the recommendation for handler lifetime? . I am starting with 6 hours to start with

Comment: @SehishnuRam I have never changed the HTTP handler lifetime, to a value other than the default of 2 minutes, so I'm not able to provide you any kind of guidance on that. I would suggest not to change the default HTTP handler lifetime unless you have very specific reason to do that.

Comment: @SehishnuRam so my suggestion is starting by leaving the default lifetime unchanged and test your system. Unless you encounter an issue that you can demonstrate being related to the HTTP handler lifetime, do not change the defaults. If you need some guidance on when to change the default handler lifetime and what considerations to do in that case, I would suggest you to open an issue on the ASP.NET core github repository or search through the existing issues. (consider you can open an issue even to simply ask a question)

Comment: @SehishnuRam but again, why do you want to customize the default handler lifetime ? Have you encountered a specific issue with the defaults ? If so, please open a new stackoverflow question and describe the details of the issue you have encountered.

Comment: why do we want to leave it as default ? when we are sure we dont do DNS updates frequently

Comment: @SehishnuRam you are not in control over network, DNS, proxies and stuff like that. So how can you say that DNS won't change frequently ? Based on my experience evaluating sensible defaults for intrastructural configurations is difficult, so I prefer to rely on sensible defaults provided by expert people. I prefer to make changes and customize things only after a reproducible issue happens.

Comment: @SehishnuRam here people much smarter than me is discussing this problem, take a look https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42219

Answer (score -1):

The concept of token expired and HttpDelegationHandler is just quite un-relative.
One that should stick with `HttpRequestMessage` and the other should stick with `HttpClient`.

In short, you're trying to interact with the request, response in the exact time that the request was sent, which possibility can get an unauthorize response. That can be done right, but it's quite complicated.

Instead, why not just consider another approach ? Like a background service that run every 30 mins, if your token expire in 3 hour or less, take a new token and store it either on cache or database ? I think that just much more clean and easier than the way you're trying to solve the same problem.