# HttpClient is sending request cookies from other requests' responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, dotnet-httpclient

We have a Web API (.NET Core 5) which passes the request on to another remote Web API.

The Web API grabs some cookies from the incoming request and appends them to the outgoing request.

Normally this works fine and we see the request cookies arriving at the remote Web API.

But when multiple requests are sent simultaneously, the cookies from one incoming request are somehow **leaking over into the outgoing request of another**.

This even happens when using totally separate users and totally separate browsers.

Things I've tried and confirmed:

- The code which copies the cookies from incoming request to outgoing request works perfectly fine. In fact even when the cookies appearing on the remote API are "leaked", my custom logging suggests it still worked as expected
- I can see the expected/leaky request cookie on the remote Web API (in its raw IIS logs), so it can't be the remote API adding it to the request in its pipeline.
- Added logging to the HttpClient call but can't see the unexpected cookies being sent.
- This doesn't happen locally
- My feeling is something is happening in HttpClient somehow??
- **UPDATE 1** I added logging to `CopyCookieHandler` and it only gets created once and reused by all requests
- **UPDATE 2** I just read that `HttpMessageHandler` instances results in `CookieContainer` objects being shared...which may possible explain this... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookies
  [image: Cookies]

The first API has this setup to use HttpClient:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor()
services.AddHttpClient<IRemoteService, RemoteService>()
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<CopyCookieHandler>();
services.AddTransient<CopyCookieHandler>();
```

where

```
public class RemoteService : IRemoteService
{
   private HttpClient _client;
   public RemoteService(HttpClient client)
   {
      _client = client;
   }

   public async Task Get()
   {
      var request = new HttpRequestMessage("POST", "http://example.com");
      await MakeCall(request);
   }
}
```

The `CopyCookieHandler` is:

```
public class CopyCookieHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
  public IHttpContextAccessor _context;
  public CopyCookieHandler(IHttpContextAccessor context)
  {
     _context = context;
  }

  protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
     //Copies the incoming request cookie and adds to the outgoing request
     var productId = _context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["productId"];
     request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Cookie, $"productId={productId});

     var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
     return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but can you use the `request` object within `CopyCookieHandler.SendAsync()` instead of `_context.HttpContext.Request`?

Comment: The `request` is the outgoing request which will be executed by HttpClient.
Usually, copying cookies from incoming request to outgoing request works perfectly fine. In fact when it goes wrong, I can't see what has gone via from my custom logging.
This leaves me feeling like there is something going wrong inside HttpClient itself

Comment: And can you maybe add a log statement to the ctor of `CopyCookieHandler`? Because for every request, a new instance has to be created, right? Maybe it is a lifetime issue...

Comment: I have added logging to log the request cookies and it still appears normal, even when it goes wrong/weird.

Comment: I don't hold any state within the `CopyCookieHandler` as such, other than accessing the Request via `IHttpContextAccessor` and I assume accessing this should be thread/request-safe, AFAIK

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but I don't see it stated above. Did you make sure to add CopyCookieHandler with transient scope?

Comment: You're caching the `IHttpContextAccessor` within your `CopyCookieHandler`. Depending on the lifetime within the DI container, you might cache an old instance

Comment: I don't  know how to explain your issue, but I think if you can obtain the needed data from the input request cookie and then set the data as a variable to be the parameter to call the remote api? I think if the data is the input parameter, then it won't leak.

Comment: @AardVark71 Yes I was and I've updated the code above. Ta :)

Comment: @TinyWang Do you mean if I grab the cookies from HttpContext.Request immediately and store them as a local variable within the  `SendAsync` method, then that should limit the leaking...?

Comment: @mu88 By "caching" I think you mean I'm injecting the dependency into the constructor...? I understood the only way to get the current incoming Request was via `IHttpContextAccessor` within a DelegatingHandler? Unless there is a better/safer way?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. And I don't know an alternative yet, sorry. But I'm getting the impression that it "works as designed": afaik the `HttpMessageHandler`s are getting pooled ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)). That could explain the behavior

Comment: Maybe check out this neat package: [`AspNetCore.Proxy`](https://github.com/twitchax/aspnetcore.proxy). I'm using it in one of my projects and I'm quite happy

Comment: yes @mu88 that it most likely the culprit. There's a fix described in this SO article : [53223411/httpclient-delegatinghandler-unexpected-life-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223411/httpclient-delegatinghandler-unexpected-life-cycle)  and there's a more detailed article from Andrew Lock on it [here](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-scopes-with-ihttpclientfactory-message-handlers/)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, but I've now realised where the problem was. See my answer :)

Comment: @peter.swallow yes, but anyway you find the answer, congratulations : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that, by default, the `HttpClientHandler` will store the response cookies in a `CookieContainer` and then append them onto the next request.

This explains why I was seeing extra cookies on the remote API's requests, but they were actually coming from the response of a previously completed request.

This documentation led me to the fix

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookies-1

[image: ASP.NET Core documentation: HttpClient & Cookies]

So by adding this code:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IRemoteService, RemoteService>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseCookies = false,
        };
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CopyCookieHandler>();
```

will prevent the `HttpClientHandler` from sharing your cookies between request on your `HttpClient`.